# Degenerate perturbations: why is it not necessary that $ [H_0,H']=0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Suppose we are doing a degenerate Rayleigh-Schodinger perturbation problem. Let's say the Hamiltonian $H_0$ is perturbed by a small perturbation $H'$, and we want corrections to the energy eigenstates/eigenfunctions (stationary states). Assume we have solved the unperturbed system.

It is always preferable to find a set of hermitian operators that commute with the perturbation $H'$ and $H_0$, so the perturbation will already be diagonal in this basis, and we don't have to diagonalise ourselves. Now my textbook says: we can just do some ordinary (non-degenerate) perturbation theory and we are done. I get this, but one thing confuses me:

> Why is it not necessary that $H'$ also commutes with $H_0$?

The only reason I can think of is that we're assuming that the perturbation is sufficiently small, such that energies of different levels are not connected in perturbation theory, that is, the off-diagonal matrix elements of the degerate part, $$\tilde{H}'_{nr,n's} = \langle \chi_{nr}^{(0)}\vert H' \vert \chi_{n's}^{(0)} \rangle \,\,\,\,\,(r,s = 1,2,\dots,\alpha \text{   (degree of degeneracy}),$$ (where $\chi_{ns}^{(0)}$ are the correct zero order wave functions) vanish anyway?

Let me clarify with an example. let's say we're considering a simultaneous eigenstate of $L^2$, $L_z$ and $H$, $\vert n, l, m \rangle$. Suppose the perturbation commutes with $L^2$, $[L^2,H']=0$. We can use this to show that:
$$\langle n'l'm'\vert H' \vert n l m \rangle \propto \delta_{l'l},$$
so states with different values of $l$ are not connected. How can we conclude 
$$\langle n'l'm'\vert H' \vert n l m \rangle \propto \delta_{n'n}$$ when we don't have that $[H,H']=0$?

Comment: Why should it be necessary ? (it's another way to say that I don't understand the question...)

Comment: If the perturbation commutes with the Hamiltonian, it will just shift the different unperturbed eigenstates. However, it is usually not the case (for example, the perturbation might lift a degeneracy, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels#Removing_degeneracy )

Comment: fawning - -it is not true what you want to "conclude" that $H'$ is diagonal in the basis of unperturbed $H_0$ eigenstates. Instead, perturbing means to replace $H_0$ by $H_0+H'$ and diagonalize this whole new Hamiltonian. It will have new eigenstates, close to the old ones, but not quite the same. Almost no operators in QM are diagonal in a randomly chosen basis - that's really a part of its being "quantum" mechanics.

Comment: @LubošMotl But for example, when making calculations for the Stark effect, you use eigenstates of $L^2$, $L_z$ AND the unperturbed Hamiltonian (the hydrogenic wave functions), you don't ever calculate off-diagonal matrix elements for different energy quantum numbers, and yet most of the time $[H',H_0]\ne 0$, so it must be that those are zero somehow?

Comment: fawning - the claim that $H'$ is diagonal in the basis of $H_0$ eigenstates is *equivalent* to $[H_0,H']=0$. Because the latter isn't true for the Stark effect, the former is also untrue. At most, due to the unbroken $SO(2)$ rotation symmetry  of the electric field, you may see that the matrix elements vanish for $m\neq m'$ etc. but they don't vanish e.g. for $l,m=l',m'$ but $n\neq n'$. The perturbed $n$-th state surely contains an admixture of other $n'$-th states, even in the Stark effect. Not sure why you think otherwise.

Comment: Maybe you only want the first-order perturbation theory correction to the energy eigenvalues? That's equal to the expectation value in the original eigenstates. But that's it. The perturbed wave functions are always caring about all the off-diagonal elements of $H'$, and so does the 2nd order correction to the eigenvalues etc.

Comment: @LubošMotl Thanks, some of the fog in my mind is clearing up. Am I right to say that to find the "correct" zero-order wave functions, we do not have to look at off-diagonal elements because ofcourse the zero order wave functions can only be a linear combination of the wave functions at the same level?

Comment: Dear fawning, we don't "need" the off-diagonal elements (of $Q$) for some purposes (and for some $Q$)... I don't know what you want to say and what's your "need". Perhaps the statement that you want to make is that $H_0$ is diagonal in the basis of unperturbed eigenstates? That's true by definition of eigenstates. ;-) But almost every operator $M$ is non-diagonal in the basis of eigenstates of another operator $N$.

Comment: @LubošMotl what I _need_ is a better textbook. ;-) thanks for your help anyway.